# Multiple PSN accounts in PS4 dilemma

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus

I have an existing psn account but I want to avail PS+ so I determined the region of my account and it listed uk (r1?). So this is the question, in order to buy cheaper PS+, I can create a PSN account in r3 (hk & sg) but I am worried about my online game accounts related to the first PSN account e.g. NBA 2k17 and GTA Online.

I set my PS4 as the primary of my first PSN account.

Will the game accounts carry on to the new PSN account which I will create?

Comment: Note, that your actions may result in account ban -  False Registration Information is one of the ban reasons, see https://www.playstation.com/en-gb/get-help/help-library/my-account/grief-reporting/banned-and-suspended-consoles-and-accounts/ ,

Answer (score 1):

Assets purchased on one account stay on that account (PS+, games, movies, avatars, etc). You cannot buy it on one account and then transfer the assets to another account.

Assets are region locked. Even though it looks like the same game, there is a different SKU for each region. So GTA-V for the US is different from GTA-V for Europe which is different from GTA-V for Hong Kong. If you create a HK account, you will only see the contents of the HK store.

This part I'm not sure of, but I'm pretty sure is locked down. I do not believe you cant buy a game with a HK account, then play it with a different region's PS+ account in multiplayer (never tried that combo). It either will not show in the dashboard, or show but not be loadable.